# Fancyhdr mismatches when trying to open file in lualatex

Tags: luatex, fancyhdr

The fancyhdr package mismatches with lualatex when trying to open a file. The file exo.tex contains whatever you want :

```
\documentclass{article}

    \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

\directlua{
    function BexInput ( fichier )
        file = io.open( fichier , "r")
        io.input(file)
        print(io.read())
        io.close(file)
        tex.print ( "\\input{" .. fichier .. "}" )
    end
}


\newcommand{\BexInput}[1]{%
    \directlua{ BexInput ("#1")}
}

\begin{document}

\BexInput{exo.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `local file = io.open( fichier , "r")`, your code overwrites the global file.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @UlrikeFischer feel free to write an answer, or should I delete the silly question ?

Comment: `frame` is not an environment, it is like `\fbox` and takes an argument, `\frame{xxx}` (it is getting an argument `\par` from the blank line.)

Comment: \frame is a scorie from a prcedent mwe in beamer, I change to article and forget frame. Thank you.